# Ruby statements in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to do something like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="avail in available_connections">
  <span><i rel="tooltip" title="Connection Requested"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" ng-click="addUser(avail.id)"></i>  </span> 
 <%= cl_image_tag({{avail.avatar}}, :width => 100, :height => 100, 
  :crop => :fill, :gravity => :face,
  :radius => :max, :effect => :auto_color) %>
  <div class="profile-connection-name text-center"> 
    {{ avail.name }}
  </div>
</li>
```

Unfortunately it appears that I can't. How should I go about getting the desired result?

Comment: What's the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this you're going to need to put in the result of the `cl_image_tag` as plain html.  Unfortunately angular isn't going to be able to deal with the embedded ruby.

Try putting the cl_image_tag into another ERB page and open it in the browser (minus the `{{avail.avatar}}`.  You can then take the parsed HTML and copy paste it into your original file.

Comment: Right. A silly question as the rails code is evaluated when the page is rendered and the angular ng-repeat happens later. I will just use the resulting HTML from the cl_image_tag. Thanks.